# Form a output by combining multiple lines

Tags: text-processing, files, awk, text-formatting

I have a log file as below:

```
/export/home/got/logs/o2877612.01:job_1432787863184_159408 Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: /user/got/distro
/export/home/got/logs/o2877612.01:Module: SUMMARY_PIG
```

I want to form a final log file by combining two lines as below. Above both lines start with `/export/home/got/logs/o2877612.01`:

```
/export/home/got/logs/o2877612.01:Module: SUMMARY_PIG :job_1432787863184_159408 Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: /user/got/distro
```

Could you help in the unix command for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far, supply some of the code you have attempted and we will be able to help guide you better.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{if($1!=a){printf "\n%s", $0}else{$1=":";print}} {a=$1}' file
```

Where:

- `-F:` uses `:` as delimiter.
- `if($1!=a){...}` If the a variable contains the same as the first field, print everything without a newline at the end,
- `else{...}`: else print all fields except the first one.
- `{a=$1}` Set the a variable used in the if clause.

Output:

```
/export/home/got/logs/o2877612.01:job_1432787863184_159408 Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: /user/got/distro: Module  SUMMARY_PIG
```

I think you want line in the order as they appear in the logfile, not reversed as in your desired output.